# How to replicate source code folder structure for generated code

Tags: xtext

I created a simple DSL in Xtext. All my source files ("*.src") are in a set of folders under "src". I want the generated files ("*.obj") to be created inside "src-gen", but preserving the folder structure of the source files.

The below (default) code outputs all files in the same folder ("src-gen").

```
override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {

  // Root node of parsing tree

  val Program prg = resource.allContents.filter(Program).next()

  // Compiled code

  var String code = prg.compile().toString()

  // change file extension

  val outName = ....

  // Generate output

  fsa.generateFile(outName, code)

  ...
```

If file A.src is in folder src/one and B.src is in folder src/two I would like that A.obj to be created in src-gen/one and B.obj in src-gen/two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `resource`s `getURI()` to obtain the uri of the resource. then you can use that uri to find the segment with `src` and then take the following segments to get the path

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I was hoping there was some configuration parameter I missed :) Also, I do not like the idea of the solution to depend on hard-coded folder names (like "src").

Comment: you can use java api (JavaCode / IJavaProject / IPackageFragmentRoot) to find out what sourcefolders are. or you try to use StorageToUriMapper
org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.getCurrentSourceFolder(IBuildContext, Delta)

(this is eclipse ui api so you need some means to handle this in standalone and ui mode differently)